# Git + GitLab (Сluster)

Tags: git, github, gitlab

Товарищи проконсультируйте. Возможно ли поднятие гит лаб локально.
И если такое возможно. Можно ли их синхронизировать между собой.
Допустим картина такая есть 3 сервера. (На каждом поднят гит лаб если таковая возможность есть)
Прод, Локльный, Бекап.
Как только на локальном гит лабе добавили изменения в репризиотории. Они сразуже уходят на прод, с прода автоматом на бекап.
То есть логика в том что работает 3 хранилища. (Не репризиотория а 3 хранилища и там могут быть какие угодно репризиотории) Но логика такая.
Ибо думаю поднимать гит лаб на росбери пай. Боюсь утраты кода (Репризиоториев)
Хочеться перестроховаться. Открывать публично что бы был доступ нельзя.
Вопрос как это сделать, возможно ли?

Comment: 1. Синхронизация реп в Лабе есть, называется [зеркалирование](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/mirror/). 2. Гитлаба во многих местах использует SSL, поэтому при локальном подъеме скорее всего намучаетесь. По крайней мере я намучался - самоподписанные сертификаты для локальных доменов, CA certs, ... 3. Есть докер образ gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest - можно сделать через него

Answer (score 1):

Если локально - это на изолированном от интернета и контролируемом вами сервере - то да, можно.

Описанная вами синхронизация называется зеркалированием (mirroring) и поддерживается "из коробки".

Settings -> Repository -> Mirroring repositories

Подробная инструкция есть в официальной документации:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/mirror/

Comment: ваша ссылка блокируется санкциями. можно было бы простыми словами рассказать.

Comment: @AlexGlebe, краткая инструкция есть в самом меню Settings -> Repository -> Mirroring repositories